# Acid Dissociation

Tags: acid-base

I have a small confusion

If suppose HA is a acid then ,  HA gives H+ and A- ions in water.

The presence of H+ implies that the solution is acidic.

OK fine... but I came across that this solution will have OH- ions too.

I am confused, from where is it coming from ? Sources tell me that it could be from self ionisation of water but I didnt quite understand the logic.

Can someone please explain this ? p.s still a newbie..Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: _Everything_ has both H+ and OH- ions. It is their **quantity** that matters.

Comment: When I say $\ce{HCl}$ you'd imagine I'm talking about the acid, but I'm talking about the gas. When you dissolve a particular concentration of this gas in water it gives an acid of a particular molarity. Hence every acid will dissociate into $\ce{H+}$ & $\ce{A-}$ ions. The constituent ions of the water used to make this acid, similarly seperate into $\ce{H+}$ & $\ce{OH-}$ ions. Bonus point - the acid just has more number of $\ce{H+}$ relative to a neutral solution - like water has equal $\ce{H+}$ & $\ce{OH-}$

Comment: @Desai ok so basically water disassociates to H+ and OH- ions and the introduction of HCl gas gives more H+ ions and hence the acidic character is explained. Is water always present as H+ and OH- ions ?

Comment: Yes, you've got it. Uh what else do you think water could be present as? Tell me what's going on in your mind?

Comment: @puma You'll learn more about acids in the  'equilibrium' chapter NCERT Chemistry. How they dissociate and how the pH is affected etc.

Comment: @Desai I thought water will be present as H2O only and doesn't dissociate easily ... and yes that chapter is the one from where I am getting my doubts

Comment: No. The lone pair of electrons in $\ce{H2O}$ and the difference in electronegativity in H—Cl causes this.